# In full calendar year view some months are missing in case of weekend false

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCDdA.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txSsn.png)

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
left: 'prev,next',
center: 'title',
right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month,timelineCustom, agendaWeekend',
},
defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
viewRender: renderViewColumns,
allDaySlot:false,
displayEventTime: false,
weekends:false,
nowIndicator:true,
titleRangeSeparator:' \u2013 ',
buttonText:{
agendaDay:'Day',
agendaWeek:'Week',
month:'Month',
listWeek:'Year'
}  ,

```
            views: {
                timelineCustom: {
                    type: 'timeline',
                    buttonText: 'Year',
                    slotDuration: { months: 1 },
                    dateIncrement: { years: 1 },
                    visibleRange: function (currentDate) {
                        
                        return {
                            start: currentDate.clone().startOf('year'),
                            end: currentDate.clone().endOf("year")
                        };
                    }
                }
            },
            
        });
```

Comment: can you describe the problem better? can you add more details?

Comment: @Corsaro As you can see on this codepen page Month of May, Aug and Dec is missing : - https://codepen.io/prvn007/pen/dyOabZY

Comment: corsaro  As you can see on this codepen page Month of May, Aug and Dec is missing : - codepen.io/prvn007/pen/dyOabZY